# Will SQL Server NOLOCK hint return partially written rows?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, nolock

First of all I'm not asking if NOLOCK should or should not be used. Let's get past that.

I guess the question comes down to how sql server writes data?  Is an entire row written at once or does it write it a column at a time?

I'm asking because the NOLOCK hint is being considered.  A dirty read is fine as long as the entire row is returned (or not returned).  Partially written rows are not acceptable.

Comment: [For LOB/ Off row data this might be possible](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5289683/73226)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. Data modification operations like inserts, updates and deletes are protected by low level physical [Latches](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa224727(SQL.80).aspx). All data access operations, including lock-free SELECT, are obliged to conform to the latching protocol. The result is that partial writes are never seen by any reader.

Answer (score 4):

**Contrary** to what is said in the other two answers: **You can get torn reads.**

One case is when you have a Key Lookup, so the non-clustered index has the old version of the data and the clustered index has the new version.

A second case is on LOB columns, so any `varchar(max)` `nvarchar(max)` `varbinary(max)` `xml` `text` `ntext` `image` columns.

A single page cannot be updated simultaneously, due to latching (this is separate from locking and cannot be disabled), but multiple pages can be written simultaneously. This is not an issue with in-row data, because a row cannot span multiple pages, it only manifests on LOB data, even if it fits on exactly one page, because it lives off-row.

This is demonstrated in [this link](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/6072/sql-server-nolock-anomalies-issues-and-inconsistencies/):

Creation script

```sql
CREATE TABLE dbo.SingleRow
(
    RowID int NOT NULL,
    LOB1 varchar(max) NOT NULL,
    LOB2 varchar(max) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT pk_SingleRow PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED(RowID)
);

INSERT dbo.SingleRow(RowID,LOB1,LOB2) VALUES(1,
  REPLICATE(CONVERT(varchar(max),'X'),16100),
  REPLICATE(CONVERT(varchar(max),'X'),16100));
```

Session 1

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;

DECLARE @AllXs varchar(max) = REPLICATE(CONVERT(varchar(max), 'X'), 16100),
        @AllYs varchar(max) = REPLICATE(CONVERT(varchar(max), 'Y'), 16100); 

WHILE 1 = 1
BEGIN
    UPDATE dbo.SingleRow
    SET LOB1 = @AllYs, LOB2 = @AllYs
    WHERE RowID = 1;

    UPDATE dbo.SingleRow
    SET LOB1 = @AllXs, @LOB2 = @AllXs
    WHERE RowID = 1;
END;
```

Session 2

```sql
DECLARE @bad_row int = 0, 
        @bad_tuple int = 0,
        @LOB1 varchar(max) = '',
        @LOB2 varchar(max) = '',
        @AllXs varchar(max) = REPLICATE(CONVERT(varchar(max), 'X'), 16100),
        @AllYs varchar(max) = REPLICATE( CONVERT(varchar(max), 'Y'), 16100);

WHILE @bad_row + @bad_tuple < 2
BEGIN
    SELECT @LOB1 = LOB1, @LOB2 = LOB2
      FROM dbo.SingleRow WITH(NOLOCK)
      WHERE RowID = 1;

    IF @LOB1 <> @LOB2 AND (@LOB1 IN (@AllXs,@AllYs)) AND (@LOB2 IN (@AllXs,@AllYs))
    BEGIN
      -- corrupt row (one column before an update, one column after update)
      SET @bad_row = 1;
      PRINT 'Corrupt row. LOB1 = ' + LEFT(@LOB1, 10) + '...' + RIGHT(@LOB1, 10)
          + '..., LOB2 = ' + LEFT(@LOB2, 10) + '...' + RIGHT(@LOB2, 10);

      BREAK;
    END

    IF @LOB1 NOT IN (@AllXs, @AllYs) 
    BEGIN
      -- corrupt tuple (one LOB page from before an update, one LOB page from after)
      SET @bad_tuple = 1;
      PRINT 'Corrupt value. LOB1 = ' + LEFT(@LOB1, 10) + '...' + RIGHT(@LOB1, 10);

      BREAK;
    END
END;
```

Note also that there are many other effects of `NOLOCK`, not least that **you can read the same row twice, or not at all, and differently in different references of the same table**. This might affect queries which expect a unique join, which could double up your joins.

Comment: Good point, added. The NCI will always be older I think, because clustered indexes are updated first.