# What are the circumstances which make NOLOCK risky?

Tags: sql-server, nolock

I've read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452996/is-the-nolock-sql-server-hint-bad-practice) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1511356/will-sql-server-nolock-hint-return-partially-written-rows).

My question is: What are the circumstances which make NOLOCK risky?

1. large rows with enough data that it can cross a page. This requires a large number of columns or varchar(max) nvarchar(max) varbinary(max) xml text ntext or image columns.
2. A non clustered index PK lookup.
3. The row was involved in a transaction which was subsequently rolled back.
4. database maintenance can still cause data movement and errors
5. If you have a variable width column and you expand it with an update, it could get moved to a new page. Anything that causes data to move to a new page can be a problem. Data movement between pages can cause a "Error 601: Could not continue scan with NOLOCK due to SQL Server data movement. [[3]](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3289/error-601-could-not-continue-scan-with-nolock-due-to-sql-server-data-movement/)

1 and 2 can be found here "[torn reads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1511356/will-sql-server-nolock-hint-return-partially-written-rows?rq=2)"

Are there any other circumstances which can cause partial/incorrect rows returned?

Comment: It's actually worse - you can miss rows, see duplicates, cause data corruption or throw errors, while taking a wider schema lock. Why are you asking? If you look whether it's safe to use NOLOCK in your case, probably not

Comment: You'll find better explanations in Brent Ozar's articles like [NOLOCK Is Bad And You Probably Shouldn’t Use It.](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2021/11/nolock-is-bad-and-you-probably-shouldnt-use-it/), [“But NOLOCK is okay when my data isn’t changing, right?”](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2019/08/but-nolock-is-okay-when-the-data-isnt-changing-right/) and more, where he explains the problems and the few cases where it's OK to use it (when you don't care about inaccurate results). An SO answer can't go very deep into complex subjects

Comment: In [“But NOLOCK Is Okay When My Data Isn’t Changing, Right?”](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2019/08/but-nolock-is-okay-when-the-data-isnt-changing-right/) Brent Ozar explains that the results may change because *other* transactions cause rows to move around while in [“But Surely NOLOCK Is Okay If No One’s Changing Data, Right?”](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2021/01/but-surely-nolock-is-okay-if-no-ones-changing-data-right/) index maintenance in an otherwise static database may change the results

Comment: Yes, Brent Ozar clearly demonstrates my points 2 and 3. I'm not seeing anything else. Index maintenance problems happen on non PK indexes. This topic has had a lot of serious discussion and I'm just trying to understand it well.

Comment: Didn't you ask this already? What are you trying to figure out?

Comment: No, this is a different question and it has been useful to me. I now have 5 in my list, not 3 :-). Again, I'm just trying to understand it well. I like to understand the why behind nolock is evil.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly:

> large rows that can cross a page. This requires a large number of columns or `varchar(max)` `nvarchar(max)` `varbinary(max)` `xml` `text` `ntext` or `image` columns.

No, you can get that even on a single one of those columns, where the data is stored off-row, so any case where it's more than 8kb.

> The row was involved in a transaction which was subsequently rolled back.

No, you can  get problems even if the transaction **wasn't** rolled back. If you have a page split, or the row is moved in the index sort to a different page), then the row could have been read twice, or not at all, or different each time.

And it doesn't have to be that row, it just needs to be on a page which is being changed. It could even be an index or table rebuild.

---

Other possible problems:

- If you get an allocation-order scan then you may be subject to error 601

> Could not continue scan with NOLOCK due to data movement

- It would also apply an *extra* `BULK_OPERATION` lock, which may cause *more* blocking on other queries.
- You can end up with worse blocking if there is a `Sch-M` schema modification lock ongoing.
- **Most importantly,** in my opinion: it's all very well saying "I don't care if I read a row twice, or not at all", but what happens if the row is part of an `INNER JOIN` query, where that row is expected to exist uniquely exactly once? You would double up your **entire** resultset, or zero out the **entire** resultset, because of the join condition.

---

Bottom line, there is **almost never a reason** to use `NOLOCK`.

If you want performance and think no-one is changing the table anyway, then just use `WITH (TABLOCK)` and be done.

Or if you are sure no-one is *ever* going to change anything in your database then set it to `READ_ONLY` and no locks will get taken in the first place.

And if you are worried about blocking then use `SNAPSHOT` or `READ COMMITTED SNAPSHOT` isolation and avoid the whole issue.

The *only* time you should ever use it is in either diagnostic queries (to investigate blocking or running queries), or when querying system tables. And if you really do need to use it, then just set the isolation level explicitly.

Comment: Brent Ozar shows that even in a single SELECT you can get different data each time because *another* connection caused data movement

Comment: Well it would have to be another connection, you can't get issues if there is only ever one connection. What do you mean exactly?

Comment: [But NOLOCK Is Okay When My Data Isn’t Changing, Right?](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2019/08/but-nolock-is-okay-when-the-data-isnt-changing-right/) and even for a single user, [But Surely NOLOCK Is Okay If No One’s Changing Data, Right?](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2021/01/but-surely-nolock-is-okay-if-no-ones-changing-data-right/) - on a static database, maintenance can still cause data movement

Comment: And that second one says "Then, in one window, I’ll reorganize the index:"  ..... "While in another window, I’ll run a COUNT(* ) repeatedly:" so two connections. Index maintenance is not static, so the argument is moot. If the database *really* was static then you could set it to `READ_ONLY` and be safe.

Comment: I don't think that you and I disagree on point 1. I edited it to make it more clear. If my rows are small, I cannot get a page split, right?

Can you get a 601 error when you are accessing the row via the PK?

I agree with your suggestions about WITH (TABLOCK) and RCSI.

Comment: Depends if you modify a column that is an index key, or the row is expanded and there's no room on the page, in both the row could get moved to a new page. Yes you can get 601 if you get an allocation-order scan, even on the clustered index (which may or may not be the PK).

Comment: That's a good point. If you have a variable width column and you expand it with an update, it could get moved to a new page. I'm going to have to do some reading about the 601 allocation-order scan.